# Flex Link not working

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, hyperlink

There this link in Flex that was working and now isnt... Flex is giving me a headache with this one because it is not throwing any errors either.

In the script part of the XML I have this:

```
private function onLinkClick( event:TextEvent ):void {
                var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest( event.text );
                navigateToURL( url , "_top");
            }
```

and then I have click-able text box on the stage like so:

```
<mx:Text 
        styleName="Link"
        condenseWhite="false"
        text="View full transaction listing"
        fontAntiAliasType="advanced"
        fontSharpness="0"
        x="265"
        y="336" 
        selectable="true"
        link="onLinkClick(event);" 
    >
      <mx:htmlText>
         <![CDATA[<a href='event:table.html'>View full transaction listing</a>]]>
      </mx:htmlText>
   </mx:Text>
```

It was working but now the link doesn't and the swf's not throwing any errors either. This is very strange behavior, would anyone know why the link won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away `text="View full transaction listing"`, you can't have both `text` and `htmlText` set at the same time, as one will overwrite the other.